# convert different string types in dates R data frame

Tags: r, date, datetime, lubridate

I have a messy data frame with two columns:

```
DF<-data.frame(x=seq(100,105,1),y=c("3/25/2014 12:56","3/25/2014 14:18","3/25/2014 14:18","3/25/2014 14:18","3/25/2014 14:18","2014-03-25 14:19:08.043"))

    x                       y
1 100         3/25/2014 12:56
2 101         3/25/2014 14:18
3 102         3/25/2014 14:18
4 103         3/25/2014 14:18
5 104         3/25/2014 14:18
6 105 2014-03-25 14:19:08.043
```

I want to convert the y columns into R dates so to have:

```
    x                  y
1 100         2014-03-25
2 101         2014-03-25
3 102         2014-03-25
4 103         2014-03-25
5 104         2014-03-25
6 105         2014-03-25
```

In order to do so, I can use the function parse_date_time from Lubridate for the first 5 elements

```
as.Date(parse_date_time(DF$y[1:5], orders="mdy hm"))
```

and directly the function as.Date for the last one:

```
as.Date(DF$y[6], orders="mdy hm")
```

I could do that by making a for and if loop, however, I'm looking for a more elegant vectorised solution.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: what about `as.Date(parse_date_time(DF[,2], orders = c('mdy HM', 'ymd HMS')))` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use  package anytime:

```
library(anytime)
anydate(DF$y)
#[1] "2014-03-25" "2014-03-25" "2014-03-25" "2014-03-25" "2014-03-25" "2014-03-25"
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this package.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass multiple orders to try to `parse_date_time` like this:

```
parse_date_time(DF$y, orders = c("mdy HM", "ymd HMS"))
```

Which should return appropriate values for each of the entries you give.